# trying to install 64 bit mint 19 onto a Asus Prime X399-A motherboard

Tags: linux, memory, motherboard, linux-mint

MB uses a threadripper 2990WX, with 128 GB memory.

at usb install
bios upgraded to 0808

```
[  0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : AMD-Vi:10APIC [130] not in IURS table
[  0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : AMD-Vi:10APIC [131] not in IURS table
[  0.000000] [Firmware Bug] : AMD-Vi:10APIC [132] not in IURS table
```

then 1 line of 2 green "|", and 1 white "|" this 3 group repeated across screen - fills 1 line
a empty line
then one line of multicolours - no discernable pattern to me

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it displays random characters and freezes? Did you try some kernel boot codes, like nomodeset, nopci, noapic, etc?

Comment: I'm a 6 week wonder in Linux.  no idea how to vary kernel codes. thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel option `nomodeset` looks most promising to just get booted and installed, and then have the chance to update graphics drivers.

Here's some links about some boot codes to try (from my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399736/3412074))

- [Ubuntu's help page on BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)
- [Ubuntu wiki on KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) and setting them permanently for an installed system

Searching for the motherboard model & linux or mint (*linux mint Asus Prime X399-A motherboard*) found a [similar problem](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=267697) with other things to try, like:

> Check your BIOS for the setting "PSU Idle Control" and set it to "Typical Current Idle". It's been available as a new BIOS setting on Ryzen boards since around late January. I've seen a few posts of threadrippers also having the problem including the main bug post at bugzilla. If it's not in your BIOS, you may need to update to current.
>
> https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683
>
> ---
>
> SUMMARY
>
> It seems to me (*a newbie*) that the specific solution in this case was to disable "Global C-state Control" in the BIOS settings. I contacted ASUS to see if they would be adding a setting for "PSU Idle Control" setting, see unpromising reply copied below.
>
> Some general fixes seemed to help along the way:
>
> - chose "legacy" rather than "UEFI" in BIOS boot settings
> - I changed 'Enumerate all IOMMU in IVRS' to enabled in BIOS, to avoid '[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[130] not in IVRS table' (I'm not sure if that was essential or not)
> - used the 'nomodeset' approach, https://linuxmint.com/rel_sylvia_cinnamon.php
> - as soon as Mint installed then installed Nvidia driver and installed all updates, including kernel
>
> ---
>
> There is another workaround that I used until AMD provided the fix for AM4. I passed the following kernel parameter via Grub:
>
> processor.max_cstate=1

And from the Sylvia link above:

> If Linux Mint freezes during boot time, use the "nomodeset" boot option as illustrated in the video [on their page]:
>
> Thanks to "nomodeset" you should be able to boot Linux Mint and install it on your computer.
>
> After the installation, reboot the computer and hold SHIFT to force the boot menu to appear.
>
> Add the "nomodeset" option as illustrated below [in their video]:
>
> If your graphics card is from NVIDIA, once in Linux Mint, perform the following steps to install the NVIDIA drivers:
>
> - Run the Driver Manager
> - Choose the NVIDIA drivers and wait for them to be installed
> - Reboot the computer
>
> With these drivers the system should now be stable and you no longer need to use "nomodeset".
>
> Note: If you're using an Optimus card, you've nothing more to do. Upon reboot, a system tray icon should show up indicating which GPU is currently active. Click on it to switch GPUs.
>
> Note: If you still cannot boot try one of the following solutions:
>
> - Try with "nouveau.noaccel=1" instead of "nomodeset".
> - Try with "noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll" instead of "quiet splash".
> - Use the "Compatibility mode" to boot and install Linux Mint.
> - After the installation, use "Advanced Options" -> "Recovery mode" from the boot menu and choose "resume".